# How to see my recent "line notes" (comments left on other people's commits) in GitHub?

Tags: github

In GitHub, you can comment on other people's commits, they are called "line notes":

[image: GitHub line notes]

How to see all of my recent line notes?

I write many per day, and when I want to link to my notes later, it is hard to remember where it was, because I have to remember what commit of what branch of what fork.